# Can't set image as background on <li>

Tags: html, css

I've already done quite a bit of searches and looked at other Stack Overflow posts, but nothing is working as a solution. All help is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PUBLISHERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ADVERTISERS</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto !important;
   background:black;
    background-color:black;
}
.nav-bar{
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px;
    background-color:black;
    background:black;

}
.nav-bar nav ul li{
border-bottom-left-radius:15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:2px dashed #E06223;
    padding:3px;
    width:118px;
    height:28px;
background-image:url ('http://example.com/sof/images/b_home.png');
}

.nav-bar a{
        text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDCWR/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the extra space after `url`

```
background-image: url('http://example.com/sof/images/b_home.png');
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/tDCWR/3/

Reference and more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the space between `url` and the source for `background-image` property:

```
background-image:url('http://example.com/sof/images/b_home.png');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDCWR/2/)**

Comment: *you don't need* should be *you shouldn't have* ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the Extra space from the value. Until then it would give you the following error

> Invalid property Value.

Which means that the property's value isn't Valid. So, you need to change and make it Valid. Here is a way to make it valid.

Remove the space and it would be like

```
background-image: url('http://example.com/sof/images/b_home.png');
```

Now, it won't show the error.